# Convert List into JSON to populate a table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, json

I have a aspx file with a table as such.

```
<table class="table .table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Row</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Admin ID</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Contact No</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     </table>
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    getAdministrator();
});

function getAdministrator() {
    $('#panelContainer').removeClass('panel-danger');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ADMAdminManagement.aspx/GetAllAdministrator",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {...
};
</script>
```

I have a AdministratorManager.cs file that contains the following code in order go get the data from MySql and create a list. Im trying to use this information to populate my table using AJAX Post method.

```
public List<Administrator> getAllAdministrator()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        List<Administrator> administratorList = new List<Administrator>();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        cn.ConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebaConnectionString"].ToString();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SystemUserId,UserId,Password,FullName,Email,ContactNo,DateOfBirth FROM SystemUser";
        cn.Open();
        da.Fill(ds, "AdministratorData");
        cn.Close();
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["AdministratorData"].Rows)
        {
            Administrator administrator = new Administrator();
            administrator.SystemUserId = Int32.Parse(dr["SystemUserId"].ToString());
            administrator.UserId = dr["UserId"].ToString();
            administrator.Password = dr["Password"].ToString();
            administrator.FullName = dr["FullName"].ToString();
            administrator.Email = dr["Email"].ToString();
            administrator.ContactNo = dr["ContactNo"].ToString();
            administrator.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(dr["DateOfBirth"].ToString());
            administratorList.Add(administrator);
        }
        return administratorList;
    }
```

I managed to get the list generated in my cs file and bring in forward to my code behind file of my webform. Im wondering how do i return this data and send it to my webform. From what Ive heard I have to convert it to JSON format but I cant seem to.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static object GetAllAdministrator()
    {
            AdministratorManager administratorManager = new AdministratorManager();
            List<Administrator> adminList = administratorManager.getAllAdministrator();   

    }
```

Comment: you can use JavaScriptSerializer class from using System.Web.Script.Serialization.using jss.Serialize(adminList) it will convert to json string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavascriptSerializer` class `using System.Web.Script.Serialization` which has serialize and deserialize methods for converting list of objects to json and vice versa.

In your case you have to do like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer obj= new JavaScriptSerializer();
string output = obj.Serialize(adminList);
```

The output is a json string which your webmethod receives as response.